# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Topic' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am quite new to Flutter and want to render a ListView. But I get an error.

I have 3 model classes:

**Subject**, **Topic** and **Content**.

This is the model file `topic.dart`:

```
import './content.dart';

class Topic {
  String name;
  List<Content> contents;

  Topic(this.name, this.contents);

  factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Topic(json['name'], json['contents'].cast<Content>());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `topics_page.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './../models/subject.dart';

class TopicsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Subject _subject;

  TopicsPage(this._subject);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TopicsPageState();
  }
}

class _TopicsPageState extends State<TopicsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget._subject.name),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              thickness: 1.5,
            ),
            itemCount: widget._subject.topics.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/contents',
                      arguments: widget._subject.topics[index]);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    widget._subject.topics[index].name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        letterSpacing: 0.3),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The problem raises at `widget._subject.topics[index].name`.

The error message is: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Topic' in type cast`

Now I need some help figuring out what might be the solution!

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

`content.dart`:

```
class Content {
  String title;
  String body;

  Content(this.title, this.body);

  factory Content.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Content(json['title'], json['body']);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

`subject.dart`

```
import './topic.dart';

class Subject {
  String name;
  List<Topic> topics;

  Subject(this.name, this.topics);

  factory Subject.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Subject(json['name'], json['topics'].cast<Topic>());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here my other model files.

Please tell me what I have wrong! Thanks!

**UPDATE 2**

Now I get the error message: `The argument type 'Content' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Topic>'`...

this is the new code as you suggested:

```
import './content.dart';

class Topic {
  String id;
  String name;
  int order;
  bool isImportant;
  List<Topic> contents;

  Topic({this.id, this.name, this.order, this.isImportant, this.contents});
  factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Topic(
          name: json['name'],
          order: json['order'],
          isImportant: json['isImportant'],
          contents: Content.fromJSON(json['contents'] as Map<String, dynamic>));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided your `Content` is a class, your topic content should map the `json['contents']` to your `Content` factory

In your Content

```
factory Content.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
if (json != null) {
  return Content(json['content1']);
} else {
  return null;
}
}
```

In your Topic:

```
factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
if (json != null) {
  return Topic(json['name'], Content.fromJson(json['content'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
} else {
  return null;
}
}
```

Finally, you could actually make use of JsonSerializer to generate all these for you, after you define your class. [Here's](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) the doc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the error: `The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Content>'`

Comment: Take a look here: https://dartpad.dev/dfeb7d1d5f1c5e4e261650f6df93f21e

Comment: what does `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Topic' in type cast` mean????!

Comment: the object you trying to assign is not match with Topic. Perhaps what you want is actually ` json['topics'].cast<Topic[]>()` instead of ` json['topics'].cast<Topic>()` ?

Comment: I am not happy with your answer... :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `var` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>`

```
class Content {
  String title;
  String body;

  Content(this.title, this.body);

  factory Content.fromJSON(var json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Content(json['title'], json['body']);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```